# Combing result of two separate models before prediction in Sklearn

Tags: algorithm, pandas, scikit-learn, modeling

I am still relatively new to SKlearn and having some trouble figuring something out.

Say you have a data set of features related to cats and dogs where the dependent variable is the animal's outcome (i.e. death, adoption, euthanasia, etc). Now I want to split my data along animal. One training set for cats and another for dogs. I then want to run my modeling algorithm for each. Finally, I want to combine those results before running a predict on the test set where cats and dogs are mixed together. Can that be done? If so, could someone walk me through the steps in sklearn?

Thank you.

Comment: this question is too broad but why do you need to split the data like this? A lot of the models support multi-class labeled data and can produce multi-class models for predicting the class on unseen data

Comment: There are plenty examples showing that sklearn supports multi-class prediction: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html#example-plot-multilabel-py

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways of doing it: by creating a feature to distinguish between dog and cat and having a single model trained; or having two models (one for each animal) and training them separately.

The former requires you to prepare the data (add this column specifying the animal).

The latter requires some code to get user input then use the appropriate predictor.

I prefer the former because its more straightforward for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am preparing the data for cats and dogs separately. What I will do is run separate models for each, then test them on the test set, also split by animal type, and then finally I will combine the two sets of predictions.

Comment: Just to clarify the "single-set" approach. Even if you prepare these two sets separately, you just need to add a column to specify the animal kind in each of these sets, then combine all rows of both sets. That results in a single set that can be used with a single model training/testing, which is what I would recommend if you ask.

Comment: Thanks Rabbit. I am doing exactly what you are talking about in your comment. Thanks for your help.